# Message Header Update Error in ActiveMQ during Retry

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I have a requirement where I have to add and update message header in case of message retry.

Here is my listener or consumer. My message is getting retried but I am getting Exception when setting the header. Please advise the correct way of doing this.

As per JMS spec and it says that Message Headers are never read-only.

javax.jms.MessageNotWriteableException: Message properties are read-only

```
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if (message != null && message instanceof TextMessage) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        try {
            String input = textMessage.getText();
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            try {
                message.setStringProperty("retryable","YES");
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying won't work for a number of reasons.  You are attempting to set a message **PROPERTY** on an incoming message which will indeed be read-only.  The message you receive is a copy of the actual message and not the one that would be resent if inside a TX and was eligible for redelivery.

To do any sort of update to a delivered message that encounters an error during its processing you need to create a new instance and decorate it with the appropriate information and then place it back on the Destination using a MessageProducer.